# Is there any way to draw Burundi Map in plotly?

Tags: python, geojson, geopandas, rgeo-shapefile

i'd like to make an interactive map for Burundi so that i can click on a region and see the content for that region. i wanted to make a map like this one

i import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.read_csv("burundi_data.csv") # this is the source the file[https://disk.yandex.ru/d/UXW5Purw1Qovgg]

fig = px.choropleth(
df,
geojson="burundi-with-regions_.geojson", # this the source of the file[https://cartographyvectors.com/map/1425-burundi-with-regions#]
featureidkey='properties.nam1',
locations='name_1',
color='temperature',
color_continuous_scale='Reds'
)

fig.update_geos(fitbounds="locations", visible=True)

fig.show()

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.